# Questions about Kafka Connection Pooling

Tags: python, apache-kafka

In my current project, I need to use Kafka to send messages. My current implementation method is as follows:
`

```
class KafkaHelper(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.topic = global_config.getKafkaTopic()
        self.brokers = global_config.getKafkaBrokers()

    def send_msg(self, value):
        try:
            start_time = time.time() * 1000
            producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.brokers)
            print(producer)
            # import pdb
            # pdb.set_trace()
            producer.send(self.topic, str.encode(json.dumps(value)))
        except Exception as e:
            end_time = time.time()*1000
            logger.info('Kafka send massage, failed, cost:%fms, error:%s',end_time-start_time, str(e))
        finally:
            producer.close()
```

`

If written this way, every time a message is sent, a connection will be established, and then the transmission is completed. Finally, the connection will be closed, which incurs a significant cost.
Can we initialize it once at project startup, create an object, and use this initialized object every time, so that there is no need to establish connections, send messages, and close connections every time.

expect:Can be initialized once during project runtime, using this initialized object every time a message is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka producers are thread-safe. Yes, you can re-use the same instance across the lifecycle of the application, even for multiple topics (assuming you want to have the same producer config for all actions; for example, some topics might use JSON while others use a different format)